# Data from MATLAB to influx

Tags: database, matlab, influxdb

I'm working on my diploma and my promotor wants me to somehow combine data from MATLAB to influxDB, he didn't even gave me a clue how to do it. That's why I'm even wondering if it's even possible. Data should be send in real-time from MATLAB to influx.
Could someone give me a clue how to do it or where to start?

Comment: Without more details is hard to help you out. This is a library found on matlab exchange to interface with influx https://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/68312-influxdb-matlab?requestedDomain=fr